# How to choose file and then submit in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, stack-trace

The UI has two buttons, browse and submit. I want the user to hit browse to find a file, and then submit to copy it to a different location. However whenever I attempt it, I get this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at me.trevor1134.modinjector.ModInjector$3.actionPerformed(ModInjector.java:154)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

"Submit" button actionPerformed :

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (mod.exists()) { //line 154 mod is a file object
            OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
            detectOS();
            modLocation = new File(fullPath);
            if (modLocation.exists() && modLocation.isDirectory()) {
                Path newP = modLocation.toPath();
                Path oldP = mod.toPath();
                try {
                    Files.copy(oldP, newP);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Mod successfully copied to: "
                        + fullPath);
                System.out.println("Mod successfully copied to: " + fullPath);
            }
        }
    }
```

Browse button code:

```
@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(homePath + "\\Downloads");
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("ZIP & JAR Files",
                    "zip", "jar");
            fc.setFileFilter(filter);
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                final File mod = fc.getSelectedFile();

                textField.setText(mod.getAbsolutePath());

                System.out.println("File: " + mod.getName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Open command cancelled by user.");
            }
            System.out.println(returnVal);
        }
```

I basically want the variable mod to carry on to the Submit area, but because of where it is set, I am unable to do so.

Comment: What's the code look like?

Comment: We need to see your code, not an error message.

Comment: post your code, and the actionPerformed method code to get help?

Comment: So then find out where the NPE comes from. Start at ModInjector.java:154. You have the source code, we don't have it!

Comment: Yep, as @GyroGearless states, the key to solving NullPointExceptions (NPE's) is to inspect the line that throws the inspection, find out which variable is null on that line, and then track back into your code to see why it is null. Then fix it! If you still need our help, then please improve your question for as it is currently written, it lacks sufficient information for us to be able to diagnose the problem nor give a specific recommendation.

Comment: I think the reason it is null is because the mod file is pre-definied, and is set in the browse actionPerformed. So it isn't set the same way for the submit button. How can I fix this?

Comment: **Very important:** which line in the code posted above is line 154 of ModInjector.java?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added an annotation in the code, it is if(mod.exists()){

Comment: @JustinJasmann I posted it.

Comment: So you're right mod is null, and you'll have to look back in your code to where you think you initialize it, because it's not being initialized. This should be the focus of your attentions now.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understand my issue now, but I am unable to set it correctly.. I have private File mod; in the beggining and then in the browse actionPerformed method I set it, I want to carry that value over to the submit method, how can I?

Comment: @Trevor: I'm not sure that we have enough information yet to be able to help. Please edit your question and add new information and code at the bottom of the current question, enough information and code so that we can more fully understand your problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have added the browse code and more info as to  what I need.

Comment: New information noted, and I see that someone has used that informatio to answer your question, good for you. In the future, please consider giving all the pertinent information initially when you first ask the question. Doing this will prevent frustration on both our parts. Please have a look at the [ask the perfect question link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for more on what good questions should contain. The link has helped me ask better questions and will likely help you too. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "browse" button code you are initializing a local variable `mod` like this:

```
final File mod = fc.getSelectedFile();
```

In the "Submit" button code you are using a class variable `mod`. Same name, different variables with different scopes.

Try changing:

```
final File mod = fc.getSelectedFile();
```

to

```
mod = fc.getSelectedFile();
```

with `mod` being a private class variable.
Also add null check in the "Submit" button code.